# Angular ui-router not loading template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building a toy app in Angular/Rails and I have most of the angular ui routing working, but it doesnt seem to display the template. I know the controller is being loaded because I put a debugger and it freezes in the chrome dev tools.

[Link to github branch](https://github.com/JeffreyCheng92/SwoleMetrics/tree/router)

EDIT: Its probably because the templateUrl specified isnt a valid route. It's injected the root html file into itself and requiring angular multiple times. Absolute paths don't work either. Still no solution.

Here's some of my code:

I also know the redirect routing works because I've tested it in local host.

```
angular.module('SwoleMetrics', [
        'ui.router',
        'templates'
    ])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
      /**
       * Routes and States
       */
      $stateProvider
          .state('dashboard', {
              url: '/dashboard',
              templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
              controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
          });

      // default fall back route
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

      // enable HTML5 Mode for SEO
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Here's the controller:

```
angular.module('SwoleMetrics')
    .controller('DashboardCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.things = ['Angular', 'Rails 4.1', 'UI Router', 'Together!!'];
    });
```

And finally the template:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>The Home View!</h1>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="thing in things">{{thing}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It goes inside this tag but I dont think this is the issue:

```
<div class="main-view-container" ui-view></div>
```

I'm using angular-ui-templates 1.4.0 if that helps.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?Is the path correct?

Comment: No console errors, path is correct. (Ive actually moved the templates everywhere around and tested but no success). Just template isnt loading.

Comment: where is your dashboard.html situated? You should provide path from your app root. So if i have controller in /app/controllers/controller1.js and templates in /app/templates/dashboard.html it should be: templateUrl: '/app/templates/dashboard.html'

Comment: app.run(($rootScope) => {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));
});  add this and show what results you got

Comment: @MarekPavelek, I just tried it and it didnt work. Also I'm using angular-ui-templates so it uses templates as the root directory for my templatesUrl.

Comment: @OlaviSau, where do i put that code? I'm new to this so I'm not certain where this needs to be run to log the error. I defined my module as `app` and then ran the code but it doesnt look anything into the console.

Comment: Your original module definition (replace app with the module you create)

Comment: @OlaviSau, yeah it doesnt log anything. I've renamed the module app and even tacked it onto the end of app.js and it doesnt do anything.